# how to display django search result in new page

Tags: python, django, forms, searchbar

i want to display my django search result on a new html page instead of the page where the search bar is. i have tried manipulating my form tag and it still does'nt redirect to the page when i search, rather it stays on the same page.

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'elements:all-elements' %}" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" type="text" placeholder="Search Free Web Elements and Resources">
  <button type="submit" class="btn bt-round" ><b><i class="bi bi-search"></i></b></button>
</form>
```

views.py - this is the view handling the seach, i dont know if anything would be appended there

```
# Search Function
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        vectors = vectors.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)).distinct()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render new template for your search results.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    vectors = Model.objects.all()
    if query:
       vectors = vectors.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)).distinct()
    context = {"vectors":vectors}
    return render(request,  "template",  context)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i want to search bar to be in in my home page. I hope you understand. Then if i search it would take me to a new page to displat the results

Comment: That's why you should render to a new template with your search function.

Comment: Okay thanks, it's working now